# jQuery( "[attribute^='value']" ) in xpath zend_dom_query

Tags: jquery, xpath, zend-dom-query

How to select all nodes with `rel` atrribute starting with "placeholder_"?

In jQuery I achieve it by `( "[rel^='placeholder_']" )` but carrot is not working when I use

```
$domObj=new Zend_Dom_Query();
          $domObj->setDocument($templateRender);
          $result=$domObj->queryXpath("//*[@rel=^'placeholder_'] " );
```

Comment: You have `=^` not `^=` in your selector.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following XPath expression that uses `starts-with()` function:

```
"//*[starts-with(@rel, 'placeholder_')]"
```

[W3C XPath string functions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#section-String-Functions)